# Drillthrough report in SSRS 2008 using parameter values from chart series?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm in the middle of creating a Dashboard System for my company and it consists of Excel, Graph and Gauge Reports that are designed in **Reporting Services 2008**.

I have a Pie Chart that contains the top 5 best Products and the number of Insured parties that are allocated to each of the Products. I want to enhance this by being able to click on the Series Area (Product Description) of the chart and want it to open/un-hide another report that will display  further display more detail about the selected product.

How can this be achieved? I know there are expressions that can be used with javascript but I don't want to add stuff that I don't fully understand, plus I won't be maintaining this report project once it has been signed off to the client. This means that anyone who is to support this system would have to have all the skills I've used to make the report functional.

I've tried by Creating the main report, then added a separate report that contains a parameter which stores a Product name. This is the filter for the data From the initial report I am able to add an Action setting to instruct the report to navigate to my more detailed report and by default it would need to pass the value of the item selected.

My problem is that I'm not sure how to set the selected Series value I clicked on in order to pass it to the other report with the value of the product. How can I achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following steps assume you have the detail report already setup and working with parameter values that correlate to chart series values on your main report. This should work regardless of chart type (pie, bar, column, etc.).

1. Right-click the series on the chart and select `Series Properties`
   [image: Series Properties]
2. On the `Action` pane, select `Go to Report`, specify the detail report path and name, and define parameter names and values to be passed to the detail report.
   [image: Series Action]

Comment: Thanks for this advice. Let me put it into practise and I'll mark your answer accordingly. Thank again

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks very much. Now I can put this together in seconds, my next trick is to try doing this so that the new chart is present on the same page.  Very much like a QlickView interface, but I think the answer lies in the use of sub reports.