# Open a sub report from chart series action in sql ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am really new to this and creating SSRS report for the very first time. 
I am trying to create a bar chart in ssrs and when I click a bar I want to pass the values to a "subreport" that embeds a path to another report file containing the details of the selected bar. This "sub report" is defined in the first master report.I followed the steps noted here [Drillthrough report in SSRS 2008 using parameter values from chart series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228312/drillthrough-report-in-ssrs-2008-using-parameter-values-from-chart-series), but still can't get the results . Please tell me what I may be missing . I appreciate .

Answer (score 0):

You probably are not picking up all the parameter values you need.

For example to get the detail behind a specific bar in a drill through  report you need to make sure that the drill through report will run with the same parameter values as your bar chart.

However at least one value needs to come from the series itself so that you get data specific to a clicked bar.

For example if you had a bar chart that showed percentage of staff trained by department for a given month. when calling the drill through report you would need to pass.

1. The Month Parameter from the report parameters group
2. The department from the series clicked which would be included in the row data in the dataset for the bar chart.
3. Your drill though report would have two parameters Month and Department.

Hope this clarifies further the item you researched above.